# multiple api jobs get Exception in component tFileFetch_1

Tags: talend, timeoutexception

I run 1 talend job with 6 jobs that call to api in the same time.

sometime all run ok all 6 successes and sometime it fails with this error :

```
Exception in component tFileFetch_1
Exception in component tFileFetch_1
Exception in component tFileFetch_1
Exception in component tFileFetch_1
Exception in component tFileFetch_1
org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 1000 ms
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.ReflectionSocketFactory.createSocket(ReflectionSocketFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:124)
```

from where it get the `"timeout of 1000 ms"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Advanced Setting on your tFileFetch that let you choose the timeout for this component. Try with a bigger value.[image]